# Number of real root of a polynomial function

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots

Let $n \geq 3$ be an integer and $P_n$ the polynomial function such that

$$
P_n\left(x\right) = x^{2n+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)x^{2n}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)x+1
$$

I need trying to prove that $P_n$ has exactly three real roots.

What I've done is noticing some properties of $P_n$ that enlight me about some real roots it has, however I'm not able to prove there is only three.

First I've noticed :
-> $P_n\left(-1\right) = 0$ si $r_1 = -1$ is a real root.
-> $P_n\left(0\right) = 1 \geq 0$, $P_n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) = 1-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 \leq 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}P_n\left(x\right) = +\infty$
-> The product of all the roots of $P_n$ must be $-1$.

Since $P_n$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, I assume there is one root $r_2$ within $\left[1+\frac{1}{n};+\infty\right[$. Furthermore, the product of all roots (without taking $-1$ into account) must be $1$, so I've guessed that $1/r_2$ must also be a root because complex roots always come by pair.

How can I show that there are no other real roots ? I've tried to obtain the variations of $P_n$ however I was not able to deduce the sign of $P'_n\left(x\right)$. Any help ?

Comment: The second derivative $$P_n''(x)=2n(2n+1)x^{2n-2}\left(x-\frac{2n^2+n-1}{2n^2+n}\right)$$ changes sign only once.

Comment: Note that $P_n$ is [palindromic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial#Palindromic_polynomial), therefore if $x$ is a root, so is $1/x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if we diffrentiate we will get
$P_n'(x)=(2n+1)\cdot x^{2n}-(2n+2)\cdot x^{2n-1}-(1+\frac {1}{n})$

we will look how many times $P_n'(x)=0$, we can use Alexander Burstein comment to notice we can bound this by 2, as between two roots of the derivite the second derivitive will have a root by rolle's theorem. In the same way we can bound by 3 the number of roots of $P_n$.

Answer (score 3):

By [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) the polynomial has $0$ or $2$ positive roots and $1$ negative one. Since $P(0) \gt 0$ and $P(1)\lt0$ it must have $2$ positive roots, so $3$ real roots in total.

The condition $n \ge 3$ is stronger than needed, and $n \ge 1$ suffices.